# Mount a folder from external sd as /data

Tags: external-sd, mount, micromax-a110

How do I mount `/mnt/sdcard/data` as `/data`. Right now the `/data` has its own partition but it's too small (~500mb) and I would much rather give it more space than move apps and other things to my SD card.

My device is Micromax Canvas 2 A110.

It has a ~2GB internal sd card mounted at `/mnt/sdcard2`
and an external one at `/mnt/sdcard` and `/sdcard`
(I'm on some custom rom that switches internal and external default mount points like that)

I don't know what filesystem those are in.

Comment: What's the filesystem on your external sd? Also, tell more about your device..

Comment: @SachinShekhar added details in the edit.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to have `/data` on the SD Card directory:

1. Copy all `/data` to the SD card directory: `/mnt/sdcard/data`
2. Delete `/data`
3. Create a symlink that points to the SD: `ln -s /mnt/sdcard/data /data`

The main problem is that `/data` could be EXT2/3/4 partition, while the SD Card is FAT32. The best thing to achieve what you want is to create an extra partition on the SD Card as EXT2/3/4 filesystem. Then you can link the directory `/data` with the partition.

When the phone restarts, it will mount the data partition more or less like this:

```
mount <args> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /data
```

Since `/data` is pointing now to `/mnt/sdcard/data`, the above command is equivalent to this one:

```
mount <args> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /mnt/sdcard/data
```

So in the end, we would have our data partition mounted in the SD card. Again, it should be in a separate partition, so we have the SD card as FAT and the extra partition as EXT2/3/4 so it won't fail when it mounts due to the filesystem.

If you want a more elegant solution, you can try any of the *XDA Developers App2SD* scripts, they let you achieve the same but without symlinking (it will mount it and bind it to `/data`). You will only need a Custom Recovery to be able to flash them. You can check them [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1716124).

Comment: What does a reboot mean in your example? The init-scripts probably want to mount the original `/data` partition then. Won't that be a problem?

Comment: When rebooting the phone, it will mount the data partition in `/data`. Since it now points to the SD card, it will mount it there and it shouldn't be a problem since we're using the same filesystem.

Comment: @Peter On Android 5.0+, any symlink at root level like /data here removed during reboot ? No ? So what is the actual solution?

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem and my external sd card was in extsd, /mnt/extsd, and the one inside the tablet was in /mnt/sdcard.

I spend 3 hours to figure this out.

Hope this helps someone.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't really answer the question. The asker wasn't asking where his SD card data resides, he was asking how he could use a portion of the SD card to   provide more space for apps and data. See the answer above.