# Mount entire internal sdcard (/mnt/sdcard2) as /data

Tags: mount, micromax-a110, internal-sd

Duplicate/extension to this question : [Mount a folder from external sd as /data](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38263/mount-a-folder-from-external-sd-as-data/38270#38270)

The device is micromax a110 and it has an internal SD card which has it's own /data partition along with other necessary partitions and a 2GB 6th partition which shows up as Internal storage/SD card in any of the USB mounting scenarios.

Since I'm using a custom ROM that make the External (bigger: 14GB) SD mount as the default /sdcard, and internal (smaller) as /sdcard2 or something I don't really need it and would much rather like to mount it entirely as /data

In the previous question it was about mounting a folder or partition on External SD which seems unnecessary now. (right?)

I have formatted the Internal 2GB partition as ext3 and copied /data onto it. How do I mount it? I have little knowledge of how how mounting work/behave in linux so I'm not really sure if commands in previous answer would work similarly (because it was about a folder, this time it's entire partition that's being mounted).

I guess I want something similar to [this script on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1716124) except that it "Mounts **/sd-ext** to /data" but I want to mount /mnt/sdcard2 to /data
. How do I do that?