# Mount /data to sd - Lenovo a7000

Tags: external-sd, mount

I came from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38263/mount-a-folder-from-external-sd-as-data). But I can't even copy `/data`.
With `sudo cp -r /data/* /mnt/sdcard2/data_cp` i get `No such device or address` and `No such file or directory`errors. And "ES File Exlporer" just Fails to copy it.

What elese can I try? I have a rooted and encrypted Lenovo A7000 and I run the commands in [Material Terminal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38263/mount-a-folder-from-external-sd-as-data) (with [sudo installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darkrealmgaming.androidsudo))

Comment: Check if /mnt/sdcard2/data_cp exists. Check permissions. Path seems to me non-existent or protected.