# Store /data and /cache in sd card

Tags: sd-card, cache

I've been googling the whole day for an answer and it has been frustrating to see how many people write with confidence incompetent solutions.
Many say to mount `/dev/block/mmcblk0p8` or `/dev/block/mmcblk0p12` in a directory in the sd card, not realizing that data is still stored in the internal memory (if this last statement is wrong then the incompetent one is myself).
What I would like to achieve is to stop Android from writing the internal storage, prolonging that way its lifespan.
There are applications out there to move some app data or some cache to sd card, for some reason no application to move the whole lot.
Any change should also persist at boot/reboot.
I've tried to modify `/fstab.smdk4x12` file replacing the partition for `/data` with an ext4 partition in sd card. After reboot `/fstab.smdk4x12` was restored to its original settings.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks :-)

Comment: Please take a look at [these answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=directorybind) on our site. The keywords are: DirectoryBind (to e.g. mount cache into a directory of your SD card), and [Link2SD](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info) (to move apps with their data etc. to SDCard).

Comment: The changes were lost because `/fstab.smdk4x12` is not stored in a persistent memory. It is always loaded from kernel during  boot. It is not clear to me what you've written about data still stored in internal memory. What's incompetent here? There solution may be wrong but you've not made your point much clear either, so a third person may take you as a troll who considers anyone incompetent just because their solution didn't work for some reason. Consider purging irrelevant text about anyone and focus on the problem only

Comment: @Firelord, I don't try things before they make sense to me. I'm a linux user and when I'm told to mount partition X here or there, all I know is that I'm still using that partition. Example: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38263/mount-a-folder-from-external-sd-as-data

Comment: Is it possible to just mount sd card partitions to /cache and /data with a few command lines? About DirectoryBind, it seems to be moving selected application's directories but not the main directory.

Comment: I've made it! In order to not create duplicates, I post here the link to my working solution: [Use sd card as internal storage and stop writing to internal memory for good](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133553/use-sd-card-as-internal-storage-and-stop-writing-to-internal-memory-for-good/135088#135088)