# Use sd card as internal storage and stop writing to internal memory for good

Tags: external-sd, app2sd, link2sd, cache

Smartphones seem to die after two years of usage, as if they knew that you just have paid the last instalment.
The common reason seems to be the failure of internal memory.
I'm desperately trying to have my phone escaping from this cruel destiny.
The idea I initially had seemed simple, but the web didn't seem to share my optimism.
This is the idea:
- create ext4 partitions in sd card
- mount at boot sdcard partitions to `/data` and `/cache` (and maybe `/preload` and `/efs` if they ever get written)

I'd like to know what's wrong with this idea and why it cannot work, but the main question is:
Can I stop writing to internal memory for good?

I've seen all the apps out there (app2sd, link2sd, DirecoryBind, s2e , you name it) and all of them seem to relocate subdirectories, never the main `/data` .
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Have you tried our site's search feature, and checked behind the tags used (most of them have a wiki attached)? That question was already asked here more than once. And besides, I've got 2 Android phones I already use for 5 years and more, my current primary device I use for about 3 years. Nothing died so far (except for one SD card, which was easily replaced).

Comment: Hi @Izzy, I've found a lot about how to increase memory, nothing answering to the actual question in the title. That's exactly my point, it's easy to throw away and replace an sd card, can't say the same about a phone

Comment: I believe Android Marshmallow has this feature built-in but this isn't so relevant for everyone else still on Lollipop and older. Hopefully can help some users.

Comment: @LJD200 almost right. MM allows to *merge* the two. But OP wants to use the external only, and not touch the internal at all – so that won't do.

Comment: Just flashed CyanogenMod 13 (Android 6) NIGHTLY version. I was given up after 2 days of researches and unresponsive forums and I started to watch videos about replacing emmc :-) ahah ! @Izzy, a one time only write could be ok, what I want to avoid is a continuous replacement of files by apps or Android itself.

Comment: That would basically mean a DirectoryBind of `/data` to some place on the external card, and the same for `/cache`. Everything else is mostly read-only.

Comment: @Izzy can I do that with DirectoryBind? Is that simple? 2 ext4 partitions on sd card bound to /data and /cache ? In the meantime I'm monitoring how Android Marshmallow is getting on. Emulated storage is in emmc, not happy!

Comment: I've never used DirectoryBind myself, so I cannot tell how simple it is in reality. I only know it's possible from the technical point.

Comment: A while ago I found this post [Mount a folder from external sd as /data](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38263/mount-a-folder-from-external-sd-as-data) and it seems to be accepted by everyone. Still I cannot get my head around it: all I can see is the DATA partition being mounted in the sd card, files still are stored in the partition!! I've noticed you @Izzy proposing this as a solution even in more recent days

Comment: Looks like you're correct with that, Claudio: it's just the *mount point* being over there, with the real storage still where it always has been. I'd say place a comment there to point that out. But apart from that, the answer over there is not related to DirectoryBind.

Comment: Cannot comment, not enough reputation. Any solution is good to me, as long as it works.

Answer (score 3):

Eureka!
Here is how I've done it:

## SD card partition and format

Unsure about which partitions I would have been able to relocate, I decided to recreate my sd card with the exact same layout of my Samsung Galaxy S III internal memory.
`USERDATA` is the last partition and there is a good reason for it:
my sd card size is greater then the internal memory and the best option has been to widen `USERDATA` till the possible furthest sector.

The following work has been done in my linux pc:

```
parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt \
mkpart  BOTA0      ext2     8192s          16383s \
mkpart  BOTA1      ext2    16384s          24575s \
mkpart  EFS        ext2    24576s          65535s \
mkpart  PARAM      ext2    65536s          81919s \
mkpart  BOOT       ext2    81920s          98303s \
mkpart  RECOVERY   ext2    98304s         114687s \
mkpart  RADIO      ext2   114688s         180223s \
mkpart  CACHE      ext2   180224s        2277375s \
mkpart  SYSTEM     ext2  2277376s        5423103s \
mkpart  HIDDEN     ext2  5423104s        6569983s \
mkpart  OTA        ext2  6569984s        6586367s \
mkpart  USERDATA   ext2  6586368s       60749824s
```

Good, partitions created.
Now, still mimicking my Android device, I format partitions accordingly:

```
# /efs
mkfs.ext4  /dev/sdb3   -E root_owner=1001:1000
# /system
mkfs.ext4  /dev/sdb9   -E root_owner=0:0         -L system
# /cache
mkfs.ext4  /dev/sdb8   -E root_owner=1000:2001
# /preload
mkfs.ext4  /dev/sdb10  -E root_owner=0:0
# /data
mkfs.ext4  /dev/sdb12  -E root_owner=1000:1000
```

The sd card is ready, now I can "backup" files from emmc to the appropriate sd card partition, taking care to preserve file attributes.

## Edit `fstab`

In the not too old versions of Android, `fstab` file seems to be always located at `/`.
Files in `/` are stored in the `BOOT` partition (`boot.img`);
it's time to learn to edit the `boot.img`.
Here are two very helpful tutorials that will get you going:
[HOWTO: Unpack, Edit, and Repack Boot Images](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=443994)
[Android boot.img manipulation](http://k.japko.eu/boot-img-manipulation.html)
a little hint:
<del>Do edit the ramdisk in your Android device.

I spent three days in frustration trying to do so in my pc, I guess is a matter of "endianness".</del>
When editing the ramdisk, do sort `name-list`(standard input) for `cpio`.
I spent three years in frustrating randomly recurring failures.

---

My `fstab` before:

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p3        /efs            ext4        noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit,errors=panic      wait
/dev/block/mmcblk0p9        /system         ext4        ro,noatime      wait
/dev/block/mmcblk0p8        /cache          ext4        noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit,errors=panic      wait
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10       /preload        ext4        noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit       wait
/dev/block/mmcblk0p12       /data           ext4        noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,journal_async_commit,errors=panic      wait,check,encryptable=footer
```

My `fstab` after:

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p3        /efs            ext4        noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit,errors=panic      wait
/dev/block/mmcblk1p9        /system         ext4        ro,noatime      wait
/dev/block/mmcblk1p8        /cache          ext4        noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit,errors=panic      wait
/dev/block/mmcblk1p10       /preload        ext4        noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit       wait
/dev/block/mmcblk1p12       /data           ext4        noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,journal_async_commit,errors=panic      wait,check,encryptable=footer
```

All I have changed is the block number (from 0 to 1).
I couldn't dare yet to relocate `EFS`, someone said that somehow you may brick the device playing around with that, still studying the subject; I do know that Android keeps writing `EFS` (I'm monitoring it).

### Conclusions and further queries

This is how I relocated the most of my internal storage data to my external sd card.
Things are slightly sluggish, as expected, but Android seems to be in perfect working order;
I can always invest in a faster sd card in the future.
I did all of this with my Samsung Galaxy S III stock ROM, you will obviously have to adapt to your circumstances.
When I finally installed CyanogenMod 13 (we don't want stock firmware, do we!?) things were a bit different.
With a wiped `/data`, CM is spending some time at boot populating `/data` and at a certain point it just give up, reboot and goes to recovery mode.
After several attempts I gave up and relocated `/system` in internal memory, now everything is fine.
I do know that `/system` is mounted as read only, but I noticed that emmc lifespan is defined as amount of read/write cycles, maybe suggesting that, unlike hard drives, reading is as detrimental as writing.
If that's the case I'd be most grateful if someone could tell me why in CM I cannot successfully relocate `/system`.

Comment: What's the performance hit?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan,
it's been a while now.
As I said, things were pretty sluggish, it was getting into my nerves sometimes and I ended up reinstalling a fresh OS the traditional way.
I was using a £5 Kingston 32GB Micro SD U1 HC I Class 10, maybe investing in a higher specs card would do.
Let us know how it goes for you.
By the way, my phone is about to turn 7 years old and, fingers crossed, it is still in good health 

Answer (score 1):

@Claudio you have raised a very good concern. Having some embedded knowledge, I can give some idea about this:

When you switch ON a device, it is programmed to boot from specific memory location. This memory location is *hardwired* to internal memory.

Usually in *demo* embedded devices, we have a small switch which we can use to switch between different BOOT devices - it may be internal, external, even serial port.

But in *production* or commercial devices, this switch will be removed.

So, it is next to impossible to boot directly from external memory.

I wish some companies can provide a option(like switch) to boot from external memory even if internal memory goes wrong.

Comment: It'll never happen... Making loading and booting arbitrary code (2 separate things, both hard to achieve) so much easier is just wiping clean their past efforts of locking it down.

Comment: Thank you @kumar for this useful piece of knowledge. Maybe it wasn't obvious in my description, but I never aimed to locate `boot.img` in a location other than the emmc

Answer (score 1):

I have been successfully able to boot from SD card on QMobile Z8 by:

- Replicating eMMC partition table by partitioning SD card on a Ubuntu machine using `parted` and `fdisk`
- Flashing factory firmware images to these newly created partitions using `dd`
- Modifying **fstab.qcom** & **init.tegra.rc** files in kernel (`boot.img`) and **recovery.fstab** and **uneventd.rc** files in TWRP recovery to initiate mounting and booting from SDCard instead of internal memory

It was successful after some experiments. I think this method should be applicable to any device with similar configuration. However, files to be edited may vary from device to device.

If you want to put only apps' external data to SD card and not the whole partition, you can edit **fstab** in **boot.img** and **storage list** in **framework-res.apk** on Android 5 and older.

For more details: [[HOW TO] BOOT FROM SD CARD [SUCCESSFULLY] on QMobile Z8 with BRICKED/DEAD eMMC](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/how-to-boot-sd-card-qmobile-z8-bricked-t3712171)

Comment: Does it necessary to edit recovery.fstab ?