# Nexus 9 stuck in reboot loop

Tags: adb, side-loading, nexus

Few days ago I started my Nexus 9 and it didn't manage to load. It started looping.

The loop goes like this:

The four colored dots circling around and then loops again - 5-6 times then it shuts down.

I haven't done anything with it - it's unrooted, original firmware, used it normally since the day I bought it (have it for about 5 years).

I tried anything I knew:

-factory settings,
-wiped cache,
-flashed original (newest firmware),
-flashed earlier versions,
-flashed original HTC firmware,
-sideloaded newest firmware,
-sideloaded an earlier version.

Every procedure ended with a success, but the result was always the same - four colored dots circling around and then loop again ...

Any suggestions (besides "get a new tablet")?

Comment: this is called emmc wear-out (and maybe planned obsolescence) fun fact about [Nvidia Tegra](https://www.hexus.net/ce/news/automotive/146935-tesla-car-emmc-nand-wear-cause-16000-user-complaints)

Comment: Sad to hear that ... tablet worked very well and was perfect for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use sd card as internal storage and stop writing to internal memory for good](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133553/use-sd-card-as-internal-storage-and-stop-writing-to-internal-memory-for-good)

Comment: By the way - my bootloader is unlocked, but I'm affraid, I don't have the required knowledge to do this. I read the links but for me its like rocket science.

Comment: oh, didn't expect that! flash twrp recovery from fastboot that will help to figure out which partitions are problematic https://twrp.me/htc/htcnexus9.html

Comment: if your bootloader already unlocked, does it mean the boot-loop can have other causes like dm-verity? this is the first thing i would try https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt

Comment: It should be possible to automatize the whole modification process. If you are interested we can provide flashable zip which can be installed from TWRP with simple steps. All you have to do is provide your free time for extensive testing. In case you want us to spend our free time in your project, please set up your stackexchange notifications to get notified instantly and mention your GMT timezone (mine is GMT+1). Aliens should be interested in rocket science