# Mount sdcard partition as /data

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, mount, adoptable-storage

I originally wanted to comment [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38270) to ask a clarification question. But as I haven't enough reputation and it seems there isn't any private messaging possible, I opened this new question.

The device is a Moto G2 with 8GB storage. I configured it under cm13 to use a 64GB sdcard as adoptable storage.
After a few weeks my sister called, the device disconnects the sdcard very often and wants it to be reinserted.

In the hope that it's only the sdcard giving up, I ordered a new one and copied the whole disk with `dd if=/dev/oldCard of=/dev/newCard`.
Have to wait, if the problem is gone or not. But I thought about, if the adoptable storage option of Android isn't that brilliant and therefore googled if I could somehow mount an ext4(/or f2fs) partition on the sdcard under /data.

The answer I found here on Android Enthusiasts, sounds interesting, but I can't believe that this works this way, as of my understanding...
So, in the linked answer, it says:

> This is the way to have `/data` on the SD Card directory:
>
> 1. Copy all `/data` to the SD Card directory: `/mnt/sdcard/data`
> 2. Delete `/data`
> 3. Create a symlink that points to the SD: `ln -s /mnt/sdcard/data /data`

So, my problem/confusion with this are the following points:

1. If I create a symlink in the root dir to something else, this link is gone up on a reboot. So how am I supposed to make the link from `/data` to some other place persistent?
2. If I make `/data` point to `/sdcard/data`, wouldn't the mount command now mount the partition in which the data is really stored under `/sdcard/data`? So the data would still be placed in the internal memory, but the point where it's mounted in the system is a different/wrong one, right?

My aim would be, to have a sdcard formatted with ext4/f2fs and get it mounted as `/data` like `mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /data` instead of the internal data partition. But can I do that WITHOUT modifying the fstab of the kernel for every update I want to do manually?

L

Comment: Why don't you simply use adoptable storage fetaure?

Comment: As said, I am at the moment. If the new sdcard fixes the problem of disconnecting card, all fine. But because of that, I got curious if it is possible to directly mount it under `/data` easily

Answer (score 0):

I have done the exact same thing in the past with a Samsung Galaxy Y DuOS S6102 by replacing all the mount lines concerning the data partition in the `init` scripts and `fstab` file.

I couldn't find better solutions (think as future-proof) for the problem because once you look at the boot process for a generic Android device in Wikipedia, you'll notice the kernel runs the init scripts which makeup the directory tree and mount certain stuff that lay the foundations for Dalvik/ART runtimes to kick-in.

So by making a few tweaks to these scripts and partitioning the 8GB SD card into 1GB and 5.6GB, I was able to make it work boot.

Note: The device I used runs on ancient technology with little security *features* as compared to modern techniques. Hence, you might wanna be careful before making changes.

Comment: So I'm right that the linked solution can't work?  Maybe it'd be possible to place a script in system somewhere, that remounts the partition from an sdcard to `/data` before the os actually boots up? But I have no idea where and/or how to that 

Comment: But isn't that happening in my answer? Before the OS boots up is before Dalvik/ART kicks in and the kernel is where I'm targeting mount scripts to work. :/

Comment: Yeah, your solution does that. The one I linked in my original question won't work^^. But the aim was a way, without editing the kernel. Because else, I would have to edit the kernel of each update manually before flashing

Answer (score 0):

This should work since what the symlink does is it looks at the /data as a folder but it actually works on the folder that the symlink is referring to.

About your issue of it disappearing after reboot. You can run a script at startup that creates the symlink. (Or you can probably mount your data directly to /data without having to use a symlink)

I have done something similar to make my [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en_US&gl=US) file system work from a SD Card. [Take a look at this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228444/278012).